# To update the locked dependency selections to match a changed configuration

Tags: git, powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm following the course [Introduction to Terraform on Azure](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/introduction-to-terraform-on-azure/creating-a-resource-group-in-terraform?autoplay=true) and at the chapter 4 I can easily [Create a resource group in Terraform](https://www.linkedin.com/learning-login/share?forceAccount=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Flearning%2Fintroduction-to-terraform-on-azure%2Fcreating-a-resource-group-in-terraform%3Ftrk%3Dshare_video_url%26shareId%3DZTNxaG%252BvTlyDu28dT31Lmw%253D%253D) with this code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.51.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
 features{}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main"{
  name = "learn-tf-rg-switzerlandnorth"
  location = "switzerlandnorth"
}
```

Then I go to sleep.

The day after I'm following the video [Creating a virtual network](https://www.linkedin.com/learning-login/share?forceAccount=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Flearning%2Fintroduction-to-terraform-on-azure%2Fcreating-a-virtual-network%3Ftrk%3Dshare_video_url%26shareId%3DU043mrdvQSO%252BH5rnMtWwNw%253D%253D)  and and I add a few lines to my code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.51.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
 features{}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main"{
  name = "learn-tf-rg-switzerlandnorth"
  location = "switzerlandnorth"
} 

# Create a virtual network
resource "azure_virtual_network" "main"{
  name = "learn-tf-vnet-switzerlandnorth"
  locatoin = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
```

Now if I try to run `terraform plan` I receive:

```
│ Error: Inconsistent dependency lock file
│
│ The following dependency selections recorded in the lock file are inconsistent with the current configuration:
│   - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure: required by this configuration but no version is selected
│
│ To update the locked dependency selections to match a changed configuration, run:
│   terraform init -upgrade
```

So I run `terraform init -upgrade` and I receive:

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azure: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure      
│
│ Did you intend to use terraform-providers/azure? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on
│ hashicorp/azure, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

So I run `terraform providers` and I receive:

Providers required by configuration:

```
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm] 3.51.0
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure]

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]
```

I'm new to Terraform.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think ```azure_virtual_network``` should be ```azurerm_virtual_network``` - you’ve inadvertently created a dependency on a non-existent provider ```azure``` by using ```azure_virtual_network``` and that conflicts with the lock file, which is designed to protect you from unintended provider changes (terraform uses the resource type name as a guide to which provider defines it - see https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax which says “By convention, resource type names start with their provider's preferred local name”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked with the issue:

Initialized code without any resource blocked, which is successfull.
Added lines of code that you added to check .

> ```
> resource "azure_virtual_network" "main"{
>   name = "learn-tf-vnet-switzerlandnorth"
>   locatoin = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
>   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
>   address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
> }
> ```

**Received error:**

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azure: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure
│
│ Did you intend to use terraform-providers/azure? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are       
│ currently depending on hashicorp/azure, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

[image]

It occurred because there is no resource block in terraform registry in azurerem providere with `resource "azure_virtual_network"` .

The correct one is **`resource "azurerm_virtual_network"`** .

When corrected that it could be initialized successfully.

[image: success]

**Successfully created a Vnet upon **`terraform apply`**:**

[image]

**In Azure portal :Vnet is created:**

[image]

**Reference** : [azurerm_virtual_network | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network)